# initialScrollOffset in flutter scroll controller not updating the view when value changes

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have a requirement where when the date matches, I need to provide a offset for the scroll controller used in `listview.builder`.

for the first record, it works as that is the current month but for then next month it still show the current month offset and not `0.0` as that is what needs to be there if the month is not current month.

```
void scrollUpdate() {
    setState(() {
      print("${selectedDay.month} == ${_selectedDate.month}");
      double _offset = (selectedDay.month == _selectedDate.month)
          ? _itemWidth * _selectedDate.day
          : 0;
      print(_offset);
      _scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: _offset);
    });
  }
```

output:

```
Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 1,741ms.
flutter: 7 == 7
flutter: 1960.0
flutter: 7 == 8
flutter: 0.0
flutter: 7 == 9
flutter: 0.0
flutter: 7 == 10
flutter: 0.0
```

this function is called first time in `didChangeDependencies()` and then after this its called on `flatbutton` function.

what is happening here ? can some one help me understand this issue ?

Comment: replace `_scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: _offset);` whit `_scrollController.jumpTo(_offset),`

Comment: @BahadorRaghibizadeh its not working for the first time but if I change the month and come back, its working...

Comment: Plus using ` _scrollController.jumpTo(_offset)` adds extra days for some reason...

Comment: you must use `initialScrollOffset` in  `initState` and use `jumpTo` in `scrollUpdate`